# fish - Run multiple abbreviations with another abbreviation

Tags: shell, fish

I have a few abbreviations that I want to run on one command.

Let's say given this config:

```
abbr command1 "echo 1"
abbr command2 "echo 2"
abbr command3 "echo 3"
```

I want another abbr that runs all of them together:

```
abbr allCommands "command1; command2; command3"
```

But I get

> fish: Unknown command: command1

How could I run all of them together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fish [abbreviations](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/abbr.html) are expanded only at the commandline when pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It sounds like you want an [alias](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/alias.html).  Just replace `abbr` with `alias` in each of your commands above, and it should work as you expect.

Comment: And note that `alias` is just a thin wrapper to create a function.

Comment: Suspected that was the case, thanks